# how to replace shimgvw.dll in windows 7

Tags: windows, security, dll, command-line

On windows XP, I easily replace the corrupted shimgvw.dll with the original so that I could recover the problem of displaying the picture on thumbnail view and opening it with windows fax viewer.

But I can't replace shimgvw.dll on windows 7. I have tried replacing from **safe mode with command prompt**, but I can't.

Is there any command-line(like sudo of LINUX) to break security so that **windows 7** will allows us to replace the file on system32 folder?

Comment: this is a programming related question... HOW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you programmer?

[MoveFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or you can use

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\FileRenameOperations

registry key.

Or you can use Sysinternals [PendMoves](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556)